# Why I get an empty response when inside the function the array is not empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to push some data to an array depending on the condition I have from the request.
So basically when a user has the share location to false, get the last location that has updated, and if the user has the share location to true, get the current location from the user.

```
exports.getUserLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const phone = req.params.phone;
  const userData = await User.findOne({ phone });
  const responseData = [];
  let sharedLocation;

  userData?.selectedTrustees.map(async (trustee) => {
    const trusteeData = await User.findOne({ phone: trustee.phone }).then(
      async (data) => {
        let locations = await Locations.findOne({ createdBy: trustee.phone });
        if (!locations) {
          return next(
            new ErrorResponse(
              `This ${phone} user doesn't have any location stored`
            )
          );
        }

        let another_data = locations?.locationHistoric;
        let locationData = another_data[another_data.length - 1];

        
        if (trustee.sharedLocation == "true") {
          responseData.push({
            fullName: data?.fullName,
            id: data?._id,
            currentLocation: data?.currentLocation?.location,
            phone: data?.phone,
            status: data?.currentLocation?.status,
            createdAt: data?.currentLocation?.createdAt,
            share: "true",
          });
        } else {
          responseData.push({
            fullName: data?.fullName,
            id: data?._id,
            currentLocation: locationData?.location,
            phone: data?.phone,
            status: data?.currentLocation?.status,
            createdAt: locationData?.createdAt,
            share: "false",
          });
        }
        console.log('response inside function', responseData)
      }
    );
  });
  console.log("response after", responseData);

  res.status(200, `Trustee location`).json({
    success: true,
    response: responseData,
  });
});
```

So the console inside the function returns me the user data `console.log('response inside function', responseData)`,
but the response of the API returns an empty responseDate.

Why does it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: The responseData array is scoped inside the async callback, so when you log it outside of the callback, the responseData array is empty. You need to move the res.status line inside the callback or use a Promise.all() to wait for all the async requests to finish before sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for..of` loop to iterate through the `selectedTrustees` which would would wait for the async request to complete before moving onto the next line in the loop.

```js
exports.getUserLocation = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
  const phone = req.params.phone;
  const userData = await User.findOne({
    phone
  });
  const responseData = [];
  let sharedLocation;

  for (const trustee of userData?.selectedTrustees) {
    const trusteeData = await User.findOne({
      phone: trustee.phone
    });

    let locations = await Locations.findOne({
      createdBy: trustee.phone
    });

    if (!locations) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(
          `This ${phone} user doesn't have any location stored`
        )
      );
    }

    let another_data = locations?.locationHistoric;
    let locationData = another_data[another_data.length - 1];

    if (trustee.sharedLocation == "true") {
      responseData.push({
        fullName: data?.fullName,
        id: data?._id,
        currentLocation: data?.currentLocation?.location,
        phone: data?.phone,
        status: data?.currentLocation?.status,
        createdAt: data?.currentLocation?.createdAt,
        share: "true",
      });
    } else {
      responseData.push({
        fullName: data?.fullName,
        id: data?._id,
        currentLocation: locationData?.location,
        phone: data?.phone,
        status: data?.currentLocation?.status,
        createdAt: locationData?.createdAt,
        share: "false",
      });
    }
  }

  console.log("response after", responseData);

  res.status(200, `Trustee location`).json({
    success: true,
    response: responseData,
  });
});
```